# ASP.Net MVC 5 Identity Roles added to database but User.IsInRole always returns false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 application utilising the new Identity Model. Everything looked to be working, however, the role collection for users always contains no items and User.IsInRole always returns false.

I can successfully add roles to users using `UserManager.AddToRole(identity, "Admin");`

This produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ponX5.jpg

The model appears to be correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8EMU.jpg

I've tried forcing Lazy Loading in the Database Context class but this has not made any difference whatsoever.

Are there any additional configuration steps that I need to perform to associate roles with users? I'm using the out of the box IdentityRole class and my standard ApplicationUser class inherits IdentityUser.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've wasted far too much time on this already.

Comment: Just a wild guess - have you tried to re-authenticate your user after adding it to the role?

Comment: Yeah I've done a manual sign out and then logged back in but that didn't resolve the issue. I even cleared te cookies just in case the role cache wasn't updated.

Comment: Did you create the role using something like `roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("NonAdmin"));` ?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it was the lack of Lazy Loading that was the issue, despite the fact that I'd set LazyLoadingEnabled to true in the class' constructor.

Lazy Loading needed to be enabled in the onmodelcreating method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Thank you for all of your input guys.

Comment: I haven't done that but still works for me :S only thing I have on my OnModelCreating Function is `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Users");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
            
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");`

Comment: I used a Syncfusion MVC template to utilise some of their components so it could well be that something in their template caused the issue. It's been driving me mad for the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the role using something like `roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
            roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("NonAdmin"));` ?
Its good to create role while your application loads for first time using that code.

Comment: Yeah I created it exactly like that.